# Answering amen to a post-nightfall mincha

Tags: zemanim, shemoneh-esrei, evening-night, amen, mincha-afternoon-prayer

If I come to shul early for maariv and it is already past nightfall and there is a minyan that starts davening mincha am I allowed to answer amen to chazaras hashatz? Sources please.

Comment: They started after shkeyia

Comment: @sam Did they start knowingly after shkeyia or was it a mistake? (ie Are they holding of Rabbeinu Tam?)

Comment: They are not makpid on zman

Comment: @sam I'm not sure what you mean: they would daven mincha at midnight? At 9am?

Comment: Sam, there are many communities who keep Rabbeinu Tam zeman and daven up to second shekia (and maybe even past that into bein hashemashos).

Comment: It is clearly a time when one cannot daven mincha.

Comment: sam, could you clarify times.  Sunset time?  Late mincha time?  early maariv time?

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: this answer does not deal with the latest time for mincha. It assumes that the question refers to a time when one for sure cannot pray mincha.

---

If it's really not the time for mincha at all then don't say Amen as the blessings are levatala.

I can't prove this for late mincha specifically, but by a late shacharit, the Biur Halacha (OC 89 sv VeAchar) says that if someone prays shacharit more than a half hour after chatzot then his blessings are levatala according to many poskim. [Note that in general the last time for shacharit is 4 hours into the day, and post facto until 6. The Biur Halacha here is accounting for a very minority opinion which permits praying shacharit until 6.5 hours.] So we see that praying a certain prayer after its time is considered a blessing levatala.

As a non-primary source, [this answer](http://revach.net/ask/article.php?id=499) by Rabbi [Peretz Moncharsh](http://revach.net/article.php?id=23&nc=1) strongly implies that he views praying mincha after its time to be blessings levatala.

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22224&st=&pgnum=74

Answer (score 0):

I would think that it would be permitted, if the davening of the chazzan is considered to be just a tefillat nedavah.  Brachot are brachot, so say ameyn.

Comment: But there's no chiddush in each berachah (or even in one of them), which is needed to make it a tefillas nedavah (Orach Chaim 107:1).

Comment: Also it can only be a nedava if you plan on it being a nedava. If you think it's a chova then it cannot be a nedava. Consider the case of someone who started davening and then realized that they already said that tefillah. The psak of the gemara is that they cannot continue as a nedava but rather they just have to stop. ie to be a nedava you have to plan on it. This answer is wrong.